# How to set title graphic on top of the title page for beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, titles

I want to set the name of university and its logo on top of title page (above the all titles). But positioning by using `\vspace`

```
  \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{GerbKievUniversity}\hspace*  {0cm}\vspace*{5cm}}
```

doesn't make anything.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locally redefine the `background` template to include the information; something along these lines (I used two side-by-side `\parbox`es for the logo and the name of the University):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{The Title}
\subtitle{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\date{\today}
\titlegraphic{}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
  \raisebox{-1cm}{%
    \parbox[c]{3cm}{\centering%
      \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}%
    }%
    \parbox[c]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm\relax}{\centering%
      {\Large The Name of the University}%
    }%
  }%
}    
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

The resulting title page:

[image]

### Remarks

- Notice that the pair of braces surrounding the whole construct are required to keep the redefinition of the template local.
- Feel free to change the settings according to your needs; in particular, depending on the theme used, you might need to change the value used in the `\raisebox`.

Comment: This is very useful to quick add two logos on top just playing with parbox and basic alignment and spacing.